# Retrieving a blogger post in Atom format using standard post URL

Tags: blogger, atom-feed

Let's say I have the url for a blog post, myblog.blogspot.com/2012/05/myblogs-latest-post.html

Using only this information, is there any reasonably direct way to retrieve this single blog post in Atom (or RSS) format?

Background: I'm creating a mobile app interface for a Blogger blog using its Atom feed.  When the blog post links to another of its own posts, I want to display the linked page in the same manner as the source page, so I need that in Atom feed format.

Any ideas?  Thanks.

Comment: let me know if you find out the answer. I posted a similar question today as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16269879/google-blogger-geting-content-from-api-and-archive-for-left-side-bar

Answer (score 0):

I came across this from Blogger API while I was looking for a similar feature. It is possible to access the data from a specific post. Check [this link](https://developers.google.com/blogger/docs/3.0/using#RetrievingASpecificPost) on Google Developers.

I am not sure whether you can get the data in ATOM format, but I think you can get response as JSON.

Update: I was able to get this information also. Should be what you are looking for - [source](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/97933?hl=en)

`Atom 1.0: http://blogname.blogspot.com/feeds/postId/comments/default`

**Note**: You can find the postId of an individual post from the Posting | Edit Posts tab. Simply mouseover the 'Edit' link next to a particular post, and that postId will be displayed in your browser's status bar.